# Maximize child window automatically when opened, when parent window is maximized .NET

Tags: vb.net

I want the child window to behave just like the parent window.

If the user maximizes the parent window, when you click the child window it must start maximized automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: To maximize a form you should set the property WindowState --> `childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you just have to set the `WindowState` property to that of the parent form. Try this

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button.Click

        Form1.ShowDialog()

        ' Set childform property to that of parent
        Form1.WindowState = Me.WindowState

End Sub
```